# In a function with return type void, what is the meaning of the statement return;

Tags: c

In a function with void return type, what does return; statement give?
For example for a linked list :-

```
void fun1(struct node* head)
{
  if (head == NULL)
    return;
  fun1(head->next);
  printf("%d  ", head->data);
}
```

The first node of the linked list is head. The expected output is all nodes in reverse order. But how?

Comment: This question could be quickly answered with a simple internet search.

Comment: ...or by using one's brain.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Is that trendy?

Comment: @Deduplicator from what I can tell, it's not particularly trendy nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` of a `void` function - means that the function will not continue to run and will return nothing to its caller immediately , we use this to decrease a time that function is running,when we have nothing else to do .

In your case it is recursive function (a function that calls itself).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

You have an `if` (as a stop condition) which is fires when you don't have a `head` 
so there is nothing to do , and you are "returning" skipping the next couple of rows just exit the function.

Answer (score 0):

> How?

```
if(head == NULL) return;    // Leave if nothing left to do
fun1(head->next);           // Process the next (later) element now with recursion
printf("%d  ", head->data); // Print the current element
```

`return;` simply ends the function it is executed in, only valid in functions with return-type `void`.